# Source for fs Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, fs

I am currently doing some programing in an HTML element. In the code I am uploading files to an s3 bucket. To do this I am using the aws-sdk node that is being sourced with like so:

```
<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.1.24.min.js"></script>
```

However I also need to use the fs node however I am not aware of a source to use that node.

This is the code I want to use: https://gist.github.com/sevastos/5804803

Does anyone know a source url for this node or a similar one that will work with this code. Thank you.

Alternatively a way to alter this code to multipart upload would be just as good. This code works in an HTML element for sending files smaller than 6MB. (Link and ID are file name identifies and not relevant)

```
<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.1.24.min.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.onmessage = (event) => {

if (event.data) {
    if (event.data[5] === "Start"){
        Start(event.data[0], event.data[1], event.data[2], event.data[3], event.data[4])
    } else{
        document.getElementById("GoogleSheetsDocs").innerHTML = event.data;
    }

}

};

function sendLoadMessage () {

window.parent.postMessage("LoadOk1", "*");

}
function postMsg(msg) {
   window.parent.postMessage(msg, "*");
}

function Start(bucketName1, bucketRegion1, IdentityPoolId1, link, ID) {
    var bucketName = bucketName1;
    var bucketRegion = bucketRegion1;
    var IdentityPoolId = IdentityPoolId1;
    AWS.config.update({
                  region: bucketRegion,
                  credentials: new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
                      IdentityPoolId: IdentityPoolId
                  })
              });

              var s3 = new AWS.S3({
                  apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
                  params: {Bucket: bucketName}
          });
  s3upload(s3, bucketRegion, bucketName1, link, ID)
}
</script>

<div>        
   <input type="file" id="fileUpload">    
</div>    
<div> 
   <button onclick="Start('EXAMPLEBUCKET', 'eu-west-2', 'eu-west-2:EXAMPLECODE', 'link', 'ID')">Submit</button>    
     
</div>  
  
<progress max="100" value="0" id="Process1" ></progress>

<script type="text/javascript">
function s3upload(s3, bucketRegion, bucketName1, link, ID) {
    var files = document.getElementById('fileUpload').files;
    if (files) {
            var file = files[0];
            var n = file.name.lastIndexOf(".");
            var res = file.name.substring(n, file.name.length);
            var fileName = link + res;
            var filePath = 'Projects/' + ID + '/Documents/' + fileName;
            var fileUrl = 'https:s3//' + bucketRegion + '.amazonaws.com/' + bucketName1 + '/' +  filePath;
        s3.upload({
            Key: filePath,
                Body: file,
                ACL: 'public-read'
            }, function(err, data) {
            if(err) {
            reject('error');
            }
            alert('Successfully Uploaded!');
            }).on('httpUploadProgress', function (progress) {
            var uploaded = parseInt((progress.loaded * 100) / progress.total);
            $("progress").attr('value', uploaded);
        
        }); 
   }
};

</script>



<body onload="sendLoadMessage ();" style="background-color:white;">

<div id="GoogleSheetsDocs"></div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `fs` module is a Node.js built-in. It isn't written in JavaScript, isn't available outside of Node.js, and does things which the APIs provided to JS in the browser do not make possible (like reading and writing local files!).

Comment: Thank you. I think someone mentioned something called "FileReader" instead and linked me to this: https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/ Do you know how I could use this? Or any other way I could get the code to work in an HTMl element. All I need is to be able to do MultiPart (or large) uploads to an s3 bucket.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access Node.js APIs from the browser. Node.js is a different execution environment than the web browser and thus has different capabilities. The web browser has restrictions on what you can do for security reasons.

I see in your comment

> All I need is to be able to do MultiPart (or large) uploads to an s3 bucket.

In this case, you can generate a presigned s3 url on your server and then send that to the client when you are allowing them to upload. The presigned URLs are valid for a certain duration. You should only generate them server side because you will need to provide IAM credentials to create the URL.

Check out this tutorial for more information: https://softwareontheroad.com/aws-s3-secure-direct-upload/

Comment: Thank you for the link, I have already looked there. The code requires aws-sdk and express. Do you know if express as a source I can use in html?

Comment: @Anralore No you'll need to run express in node.js. You'll need a server one way or another to interact with s3 securely.

Comment: I am writing a small wix website. All I can access is the wix Javascript code and HTML elements. I already have working code in the HTML element that uploads files smaller than 6MB to a s3 bucket, but I need code that send larger files as well; such as with Multi Part or Managed upload or something. I could show the code that works for sending small files if that would help some how?

Comment: Alternatively a way to get user uploaded files out of an HTML element into the wix JavaScript would work as I could use nodes there however I have been unable to do that as it always returns an error that the file is not a specific type valid for sending.

Comment: You can edit it onto your original question and see if someone is familiar with Wix's widgets.

Comment: I have added the code that works for files under 6MB. Thank you for all your help, I have been stuck on this for weeks.

Comment: Ah, apparently I have to wait until it has been approved. Can you see it?

Comment: Can you see it now?

Comment: You had edited it into my answer, I moved it into your question. It looks like you've already asked this over here https://stackoverflow.com/q/63565978/5007662

Comment: I asked the question about the code a few days ago yes. This question was suppose to be about the fs node. Sorry would it have been easier if I had just linked you to it? I am new hear sorry. I still need to find working code that will upload large files, do you have any ideas?

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. I am very badly dyslexic.